# Adding tables in SQLite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I was researching on how to add tables in an sqlite database for more information but I can't have a grip on how it was truly done.

I have this code:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class SQLiteAdapter {

 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "SCORING";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "SCORING_TABLE";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE1 = "Assessment";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 3;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Content1";
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Content2";
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT3 = "Content3";

 //create table SCORING (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
  + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
  + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, "
  + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, "
  + KEY_CONTENT3 + "text not null);";

 private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 private Context context;

 public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
  context = c;
 }

 public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public void close(){
  sqLiteHelper.close();
 }

 public long insert(String content1, String content2, String content3){

  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT1, content1);
  contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT2, content2);
  contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT3, content3);
  return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
 }

 public int deleteAll(){
  return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
 }

 public Cursor queueAll(){
  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2, KEY_CONTENT3};
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
    null, null, null, null, null);

  return cursor;
 }

 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// If you need to add a column
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SCORING_TABLE ADD COLUMN Content4 TEXT");
    }
  }
 } 
}
```

and for the second one I'm having a hard time inputting data to the second table

```
package com.example.database;



import com.example.database.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity {

 EditText  inputContent2;
 TextView textView1, textView2;
 Button buttonAdd, buttonDeleteAll;

 private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
 ListView listContent;

 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 Cursor cursor;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);


   textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   inputContent2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content2);
   buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
   buttonDeleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteall);
      listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

   mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
   mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

   cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
   String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1,     SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3};
   int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3};
   cursorAdapter =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
   listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

   buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
   buttonDeleteAll.setOnClickListener(buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener);



   }

   Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
             int a=Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
             int  b=a+2;
          String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
          textView1.setText(s1);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   String data1 = textView1.getText().toString();
   String data2 = inputContent2.getText().toString();
   String data3 = textView2.getText().toString();
   mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
   updateList();



  }

   };


   Button.OnClickListener buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
   updateList();
  }

   };

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
 }



 private void updateList(){
  cursor.requery();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally found using ContentProviders to be a clearer and easier to maintain way to manage multiple tables.

There is a nice article here that explains ContentProviders and other ways of dealing with android database/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#tutorialusecp

Comment: thanks Corey i have done it adding a new one, now i have a new problem